# Email clients wrapping text

Tags: php, email, formatting

I am fetching the body of an email using zend library but the text is wrapped.On viewing the same message in a mail client the text is formatted correctly.

e.g. 
Original mail- How r u ? I am fine thankyou? where are u?

```
            test data. testing again.
```

Received mail- How r u ? I am fine thankyou?

```
            Where are you?
            test data. testing again.
```

In the received mail the text "Where are you?" is wrapped hence appears in a new line.

I need to remove the unwanted new line characters which I am assuming got introduced by the mail client because of wrapping.

The details of mail header: 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

How can I get the original formatting of the text and remove the extra new line characters using any php method?
How is the mail client formatting the text correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do this with php's trym

```
$WithoutLineBreak = trim($originalstring);
```

Comment: I need the original text and do not want to remove any formatting in the original text. Simply trim would remove the new line characters and will not restore the original formatting

Comment: how about pasting the orignal text here so i can see what you are working with?

the html source that is

Comment: updated the example in the question. I do not have the html source since the mail has only text/plain part